# Understanding change of variables for a function

Tags: derivatives

Given the price function $p=x-x(z+y)$ where both $z$ and $y$ are between 0 and 1 (think discounts) and x is some input price/gross price. If the goal is to see how much $p$ varies $(p(t)/p(t-1)-1)$ (t as in time), by varying any of the variables. Why is that the percentage change of price p is lower, when varying $z$ and that $y$ is larger than 0, than if $y$ is simply 0?

Whether any of the discounts are zero does not matter if for example $x$ changes and holding anything else constant.

This is something I simply observe, but fail to understand logically. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about your context? It looks like $x$ refers to quantity and $z$ and $y$ are "discounts", correct? Also, is $t$ an index of a period?

Comment: X is a gross price before discounts, and t is is time, I'll add it into the question :)

Comment: "Why is that the percentage change of price p is lower, when varying z ". Would taking the derivative of $p$ with respect to $z$ be enough for an explanation? You may also want to check about de economic definition of an elasticity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(economics)#Definition

Comment: Yes, that would work. I have taken partial derivatives and total derivatives, but I fail to understand why it is the case that change of price in percentage becomes lower whether you include y or not while increasing z.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are asking for, but let me know otherwise. Consider the elasticity of prices to the gross price:

$$\epsilon=\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}\frac{x}{p(x)}=-c(y,z)\frac{x}{p(x)}=\frac{-c(y,z)}{1-c(y,z)}$$

where $c(y,z)=y+z$. The expression above measures the sensitivity of $p$ to $x$. Notice that this sensitivity depends of both $y$ and $z$, and moreover the partial derivatives of $\epsilon$ wrt $y$ and $z$ are functions of both $y$ and $z$. This is just a consequence of the fact that when we study percentage changes, the baseline levels of the constant $c(y,z)$ matters.

Is this of any help?